# Expression Engine CSS Changes

Tags: expressionengine

My CSS is located at below location

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site/css/style.css" />
```

I ant see from where should i edit that CSS from admin

I checked on Googled no use, i checked all the files under
   CP Home >>     Design >>     Template Manager

But it didnt help am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your templates are likely calling the CSS from a flat file, stored outside of ExpressionEngine entirely. Many developers prefer this approach, and it is arguably more performant as well.

Look in your site's web root via FTP for the **site** folder, and then the **css** folder inside of it.

Comment: Thanks that helps yes the css file is on FTP